# ReferenceError: formData is not defined

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.8

I am writing a unit testing code for the Ajax and Laravel project. I am trying to test one function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#postAdd').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $('#addPost');
            formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('posts.store') }}",
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

In the browser, this works ok. but when testing I get below error in console

> ReferenceError: formData is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`formData` is not defined.

Nowhere in your script above are you defining the variable `formData`.

You create a variable called `form`, but you are not doing this for `formData`.

Perhaps you meant to declare a variable called `formData` rather than form, or other way around.